# Django REST framework with mongoDB : invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework

I'm building a web site with django (1.5.11) and mongoDB (2.4.9). As I want to add REST APIs, I also installed Django REST framework (3.0.5). But I can't get serializers to work correctly with a very simple model (see below), instead I get this error :

```
ValueError at /api/message/
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

I believe this error is related to the fact that mongoDB identifiers are not integers. Also note that I don't want to use MongoEngine (and Django Rest Framework Mongoengine) because I wan't to stay in a django philosophy.

Any clues or hints? Please find below a minimal example of my app.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox import fields

class Message(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = fields.ListField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django import http, template
from rest_framework import generics, renderers, parsers
from . import models, serializers

def messageList(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        messages = models.Message.objects.all()
        serializer = serializers.MessageSerializer(messages, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

class JSONResponse(http.HttpResponse):
        def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
                content = renderers.JSONRenderer().render(data)
                kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
                super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Message
        fields=('id' , 'text',)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/message/$', views.messageList),
)
```

Comment: Django won't work with MongoDB out of the box. You will have to install and use the libraries you mentioned if you want to use MongoDB. Why do you think using those libraries is against "Django Philosophy"?

Comment: I thought using MongoDB Engine (which is not MongoEngine) would be sufficient to use Django with MongoDB... is not the case? Besides, when I tried to create models using MongoEngine Rest Framework, I couldn't get the Django shell (using manage.py) to create objects with save() method... while it worked using pure Django models and MongoDB Engine. That's why I'm wondering if MongoEngin is fully Django-compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add id field as charfield in serializer

**serializers.py**

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Message
        fields=('id' , 'text',)
```